# What kind of polling server pattern exists for Windows developers?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, scalability, polling

Polling servers seems to be a theme that comes up for certain types of enterprise applications, particularly social networking web applications.

From what I have read, people on the Unix side use memcache that can give you a few thousand requests per second.

What options do Windows developers have since we don't have a memcache alternative? (I don't have the time to learn Unix at that level).

Answer (score 2):

I can't promise that memcached is actually suitable for your problem, but it shouldn't be too difficult to get it working on a Windows server. Check out [memcached for Win32](http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32/) for a good starting point. If your problem is big enough to need memcached, then the effort to port it or get a port working probably shouldn't daunt you.